# How to replicate a pc?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, clone

I've got a laptop given for business purposes by the company wherenI work. It has disc encryption, high security policies etc. What I need to do to clone that machine, and use is as a virtual machine. As I don't want to keep it always with me. How can I do this? (Actually a colleage of mine did this and cloned his windows laptop and he's using it in his macbook pro.But I need to do this with 2 windows machines and I don't know the appropriate applications for this)

Comment: `a laptop given for business purposes by the company where I work`  Start by talking to your IT department.  This may not actually be allowed.

Comment: Acronis True Iambe might be able to do this but understand it won't be an exact duplicate.  Get permission to remote into the PC

Comment: I asked precisely the same question to our IT department and their answer was "uhmm....... No VMs that I know off.... uhhhmmmmmmmm.. Why not try teamviewer". (This is what I ended up using as a stopgap measure).

Comment: But my colleague sitting next to me uses in that way somehow. There should be a windows solution as there's a mac solution.